Unable to locate package ros-humble-joint-state-publisher-gui
I am using humble distro. when i trying to get the humble joint state publisher package by using the command "sudo apt-get install ros-humble-joint-state-publisher-gui", but getting error that unable to locate the package

Please edit your question to explain what your platform is and what you've done to install humble. Also please include the full command and full console output. The exact errors are very helpful too. Without that information we can only guess at what might be wrong on your system. I'm going to close your question for now, but after you edit it  to make the question effectively answerable it can be reopened.

If you're using an ARM platform, many ROS2 packages are only released in non-GUI versions, which means your apt cannot perform binary installation. You can try the following steps to solve this problem:

Use the command I provided to reinstall ROSwget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fishros/fish_install/main/install -O - | bash which will prompt you for system version information. Choose the desktop version to install and then try using apt to install joints-state-publisher-gui.

If installation fails, you can try building from source. Source code can be found at: https://github.com/ros/joint_state_publisher. Building command:
git clone https://github.com/ros/joint_state_publisher src/joint_state_publisher && colcon build



When you say "system version", do you mean base OS, or version of ROS (i.e. Humble as stated by the OP)? I presume that you mean the former, but just wanted to clarify, as this page suggests that the version of ROS should be substituted for fish and fishros. Maybe [edit] your answer and add a couple of "real world" examples (just in case the OP doesn't come back with the required info). Also, it is (generally) better to ask the OP for additional info in a comment under the question, rather than in your answer.

Sorry, just joined the community to answer questions and wasn't very clear on the usage rules. I have revised the answer.

Not a problem. When you have a rep of 50 you will be able to comment.
